# Converting String to Int and adding a specific value

Tags: c#

I have a string `ABC0001`

I want to add `+1` for every new entry in the DB.

If I take `SubString(3, myStr.Length -3)`, it only gives me `1`, trimming all the 0s(zeros).

Is there any other way I can add +1 to every new entry?

Thanks.

Comment: regex would do the trick

Comment: you do that substring, and store the resultant string's length (eg for 0001, 4). Then you can cast the string to an integer (=1); add +1(=2); cast it to string again (="2"), and add as many 0s you need to fill the original string's length ( 3 zeros in this case (4-resultString.length)

Comment: after `substring` and adding one, `yourNumber.ToString("0000");`,< this will return `0002`. Then append to first part

Comment: Is the string `ABC0001` always used in its entirety, & you just need to generate it like this? Or are there other scenarios where you need to take this apart again & split the `ABC` & the number? Should these really be 1 field in your DB?

Comment: @AshleyPillay Yes, the format will always be ABC0001, ABC0002, ABC0003 and so on...

Comment: What would you do if you generate ID `ABC0004`, then that row gets deleted? Would you reuse `ABC0004`, or move on to `ABC0005`? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let's try below code. I think it will help you:**

```
var myStr = "ABC0001";
var numStr = Int32.Parse(myStr.Substring(3, myStr.Length -3));
numStr += 1;
myStr = myStr.Substring(0, 3) + numStr.ToString("0000");

Console.WriteLine(myStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, this can also be done using regex and the following code may need some adjustment to fit your requirement. But it will give you a way to go:

```
string data = "ABC0001";
string digits = new String(data.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
int num = Int32.Parse(digits);
num++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this with regular expressions

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var match = Regex.Match("MD00123", @"^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)$");
var num = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);   
var after = match.Groups[1].Value + (num + 1).ToString("D4");
MessageBox.Show(after.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I have expanded the code from hiule, so that it should work now:

```
        var myStr = "ABC0001";
        var numStr = Int32.Parse(myStr.Substring(3, myStr.Length - 3));
        numStr += 1;
        myStr = myStr.Substring(0,3) + numStr.ToString("0000");
```

I gives to me the Result "ABC0002", which I think should be the result you intent to have.

Answer (score 1):

And a simple one just using string formatting:

```
        string s = "ABC0001";
        int index = Int16.Parse(s.Substring(3, s.Length - 3)) + 1;
        string result = s.Substring(0, 3) + $"{index:D4}";
```

A complete sample program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "ABC0000";
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int index = Int16.Parse(s.Substring(3, s.Length - 3)) + 1;
            s = s.Substring(0, 3) + $"{index:D4}";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget the '4' after the D in the last line? Just copy-paste the sample program & check it out...

Comment: Thanks Johan for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myStr = myStr.Substring(0, 3)
       + (Convert.ToInt32(data.Substring(3, myStr.Length -3)) + 1).ToString("0000");
```

I made it as simple and concise as I could.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
string test = "ABC0001";
string leftSide = string.Join("", test.Take(3)); // take 3 of string 'ABC'
int num = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", test.Skip(3))) + 1; // skip 3 to get 0001
leftSide = leftSide + 
           string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("0", 4 - num.ToString().Length)) + 
           num; // ABC + repeat 0 elements according to increased num + append the new num
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with regex

```
string input = "ABC0001";

Regex reg = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
Match result = reg.Match(input);

string alpha = result.Groups[1].Value;
string number = result.Groups[2].Value;

int inp = (Int32.Parse(number) + 1).ToString("D4"); //get 0002

input = alpha + inp ; // get ABC0002
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
        var bdRecords = new List<string>(); // new collection of database records.

        string text = "ABC0001"; // initial string. Can it be initially "ABC"?

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) // looping through all needed existing records (suppose we have 100, but you didn`t provide some initial info about database records). "foreach" can be used here.
            bdRecords.Add(text.Substring(0, 3) +  i.ToString("D4"));
```

Check for comments in code. After that you will have collection of 100 formatted strings. Then you can apdate the database with it.